# Dividing MST for kruskal clustering

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis

I made a c# application that draw random point on the panel. I need to cluster this points according to euclidian distance. I already implement kruskal algorithm. Normally, there must be number of minimum spanning tree up to written number. For instance, when the user want to clusters drawn point for 3 clusters , end of the kruskal algorithm there must be 3 huge MST. 
But I did it in a different way. ***I made a one huge  MST,*** now I have to **divide this MST into written number of clusters.**
**For example, point number = 5 , cluster number 2  my kruskal output is = 0-3:57  1-2:99  1-4:102**

**from-to:euclidian distance**

*Problem is I don't know in where I should cut these MST for create clusters*

Comment: The relationship between a MST and a minimum distance cluster is not so clear for me. Moreover, if you want to divide a MST into smaller MST, what is your optimization criteria ? If you want to minimize the sum of all MST weights, then you can simply remove the edges with maximum weights. It seems more complicated if you want to minimize the maximum MST weight

Comment: @Damien Kruskal clustering maximizes the minimum distance *between* clusters

Comment: @MattTimmermans I understand that. My concern was that what we generally consider as clustering is not such MST clustering. But I was maybe splitting hairs here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kruskal's algorithm, MST edges are added in order of increasing weight.

If you're starting with an MST and you want to get the same effect as stopping Kruskal's algorithm when there are N connected components, then just delete the N-1 highest-weight edges in the MST.